# Automated PayPal payments

Tags: php, e-commerce, paypal

I'm looking for a way to automatically send money from my PayPal account, to other PayPal accounts; via PHP. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
$recievers = array("client1@email.com" , "client2@email.com");

$myAccount = "me@email.com";
$myPassword = "letmein";
$amountToPay = 20.0; // $20 USD

foreach($recievers as $payee)
    sendMoney($myAccount, $myPassword, $payee, $amountToPay); //Is this possible?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

You might want to look into Paypal's [Mass Payment API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay).

Comment: Currently, Mass Payments API is only available once you meet a certain tunrover. What api do I use If I am just starting? (I want to automaticly pay others, not recieve money)

Comment: what about a single payment?