# Perform a PayPal payment automatically using PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

How can I automate a PayPal payment using PHP?

I have the email of my PayPal business account, the PayPal email of the receiver and the amount to transfer.
Is there a way to make the money transfer without my interaction? (the payment originates from my account)

Of course I'll run the PHP script manually

Comment: **You can't.** Well, that's illegal. Breaks the ToS. Even though you are the owner or the payer, it is not possible.

Comment: Seriously? I can't pay someone? :-) I think it's possible to automate payments if you grant the permission in your PayPal account

Comment: Yes buddy. You can pay someone, but not "automate" it using scripts, **without user interaction**.

Comment: Ehm... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/

Comment: Looks like it can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372060/automated-paypal-payments

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini But I really feel there's some kinda insecurity in this.

Comment: Looks like there are restrictions in place.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No dude, it's from the PayPal API and you need to explicitly set the permission to do so. Of course the amount to pay and the exact circumstances in which the payment is made is computed by the PHP script, not by the final user

Comment: @PraveenKumar well if a hacker found a backdoor, that would be... very bad lol. Though if you have a popular business that requires giving out payments to thousands of people per month, if not more, I can definitely see the appeal in not having to do it manually or employee strange HUMANS to do the job.

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini See Webeng's above comment. :D

Comment: What if I find a Trojan Cat? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question:

It's possible to make a PayPal payment using PHP only, it's called [Implicit approval payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Implicit approval payments are payments where the sender and the API caller are using the same account. Because PayPal draws the funds for the payment from your own account, there is no approval necessary, and as such there is no visible flow for implicit approval payments.

I tried using the `Pay` API and the payment is made within the PHP script, no need for a web flow or any other manual approvement.

The Pay API requires an extra field, called `senderEmail`, set this field to the PayPal email user account